# Errors installing pg with npm on Windows 8

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm

Trying to use npm to install Postgre and getting an error. I've repaired/checked relevant installations (PostgreSQL, Visual Studio, Node, Express) numerous times. Any help you can give is VERY appreciated! I'm running 64-bit Windows 8.

```
npm WARN package.json node-api@ No description
npm WARN package.json node-api@ No repository field.
npm WARN package.json node-api@ No README data
npm WARN package.json path@0.4.9 path is also the name of a node core module.

> pg@3.4.1 install C:\StrikeBack\node_modules\pg
> node-gyp rebuild || (exit 0)


C:\StrikeBack\node_modules\pg>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild 
'pg_config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

gyp: Call to 'pg_config --includedir' returned exit status 1. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\StrikeBack\node_modules\pg
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.30
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
pg@3.4.1 node_modules\pg
├── packet-reader@0.2.0
├── pg-connection-string@0.1.1
├── pg-types@1.4.0
├── generic-pool@2.1.1
├── buffer-writer@1.0.0
├── nan@1.2.0
└── pgpass@0.0.3 (split@0.3.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL 'bin' directory (e.g. `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin`) is not in your path. Add it and try re-installing.

Comment: Still going poorly. The problem still seems to be with node-gyp. Now I get, among other messages, the following:

 c:\users\mose\.node-gyp\0.10.30\deps\uv\include\uv-private/uv-win.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No such file or directory [C:\StrikeBack\node_modules\pg\build\binding.vcxproj]

Comment: Do you have VS Express installed or the paid VS installed? If the Express edition, you may need to install the Windows SDK too if you haven't already.

Comment: I have both installed. Still having problems. I've repaired all installs several times, too. And I do have PostgreSQL (9.3) installed.